# How to find a Derived Class of a Generic Base Class when you only know the type of the Generic Base Class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, types

How to find a Derived Class of a Generic Base Class when you only know the type of the Generic Base Class?

I've tried with the below method but doesnt compile:

```
private Type FindRepositoryType(Type entityType)
{
    var repoTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                            .Where(t => t.BaseType != null
                                && t.BaseType.IsGenericType
                                && t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseRepository<entityType>))
                            .ToList();
    return null;
}

var repoType = FindRepositoryType(typeof(Product));
```

I'm hoping to find the ProductRepository type:

```
public class ProductRepository : BaseRepository<Product>
{

}
```

Comment: You want to get derived classes of base class using base class, doesn'y you?

Comment: No, using the Base Class Generic Type, the T.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your  `Where` clause with:

```
.Where(t => t.BaseType != null
         && t.BaseType.IsGenericType
         && t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (BaseRepository<>)
         && t.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().Single() == entityType)
```

Comment: where is GenericTypeArguments? I'm using .NET 4.0, it's not there.

Comment: @TheLight sry, misunderstood your question prior to the edit - I've edited to make it 4.0 compatible.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly shorter alternative to the other answers (which also doesn't rely on the .NET 4.5 `GenericTypeArguments` property) could be:

```
// Create a type that represents `BaseRepository` with `entityType` as the generic parameter
var expectedType = typeof(BaseRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
// verify that it actually exists in the current assembly (will throw if it doesn't)
return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Single(p => p.BaseType == expectedType);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were not too far off.

[`GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) will return the generic type without any type parameters. In your case, this will be `BaseRepository<>` (note the empty brackets). If you want to match the generic type arguments too, you will need to use [`GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) as well. So your check will be this:

```
t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseRepository<>) && 
t.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == entityType
```

While `GetGenericArguments()` returns an array of types, you can be sure that there will be one, as you just before ensured that the generic type definition is `BaseRepository<>` which has *exactly* one type argument.

Finally, you also want to return the type you find, instead of `null`:

```
private Type FindRepositoryType (Type entityType)
{
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.BaseType != null
            && t.BaseType.IsGenericType
            && t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseRepository<>)
            && t.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == entityType)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```